# Como autenticar um usuário via requisição HTTP?

Tags: java, autenticação, autenticação-http, vbulletin

Estou tentando autenticar usuários em um fórum [VBulletin](http://www.vbulletin.com/) por meio de uma aplicação *desktop* utilizando componentes do pacote `swing`, o código está funcionando mas acredito que esta não é a melhor forma de se fazer.

#### Lógica

Eu usei o plugin [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/es-es/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) no Firefox para encontrar os atributos a serem enviados no formulário de login. São eles:

```
vb_login_md5password --> A senha em MD5
vb_login_md5password_utf --> Idem ao anterior
vb_login_username --> Nome de usuário
```

Então eu criei uma String com esses parâmetros, ficando assim:

```
String query = "do=login&url=index.php" // url de login
              + "&vb_login_md5password=" + password // a senha já em MD5
              + "&vb_login_md5password_utf=" + password // a senha novamente
              + "&s=&securitytoken=guest&vb_login_username=" + username // o nome de usuário
              + "&vb_login_password="; // !importante
```

Em seguida eu faço uma requisição para a página de login por meio de uma `HttpURLConnection` e recebo o código `HTML` da página seguinte - que pode ser uma página de erro ou a página correta caso a autenticação esteja correta. Então eu procuro por uma informação que só um usuário logado conseguiria ver, no caso é uma mensagem escrito "Bem vindo {nome do usuário}" logo no inicio do código `HTML`.

#### O problema...

... é que todo o código fonte `HTML` da página é baixado para então ser procurado dentro dele pela `String` "Bem Vindo" que encontra-se logo no inicio, ou seja, está baixando muita informação além do necessário. Não acredito que esta seja a melhor forma de se fazer, já estou pensando em performance, alguns fóruns podem ter muitos sub-fóruns e esse download do código seguido pela procura da palavra pode ser muito lento.

Outro problema é que, um usuário pode mudar o idioma do fórum. Supondo que ele esteja usando a versão em inglês (definida nas preferências no fórum) a minha lógica seria inútil pois não haveria uma palavra "Bem vindo" e sim "Welcome". Então, mesmo que o nome de usuário e a senha estivessem corretas a autenticação não ocorreria - na aplicação, por conta da lógica.

Fiz algumas pesquisas e encontrei o [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/), mas ele serve para extrair e manipular informações de um código HTML (por exemplo, pegar um valor pelo ID) e não é o que eu estou querendo.

**PS**: Não preciso de mais informações sobre o usuário. É bem simples, bastaria apenas saber se ele é membro de um determinado fórum, i.e, se ele possui uma conta. *Autenticou = possui conta, é membro. Não autenticou = não é membro*.

---

Como posso autenticar um usuário em fóruns VBulletin por meio de uma conexão HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de várias tentativas encontrei uma solução utilizando [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) mesmo com uma [documentação](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html) um tanto quanto complicada consegui fazer a autenticação de um usuário em um fórum VBulletin. Antes de compartilhar o código, gostaria de informar:

#### Formulário e `submit`:

Aos interessados, é possível obter qualquer elemento da página pelo `id` ou pelo `name` com o [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). No formulário de login tanto o `<input>` de nome de usuário quanto o de senha possuem um `name` definido, o problema é que não há nenhum modo de pegar o botão de `submit` pois ele não existe, provavelmente o formulário é submetido de um arquivo Javascript. Para resolver esse problema eu criei um "botão *fake*" e o inseri dentro do formulário de login (é possível fazer isso com HtmlUnit), assim pude disparar o `submit` do `form`.

#### Autenticação:

Após enviar a requisição criei um `CookieManager` para obter os *cookies* junto a resposta retornada pelo servidor. Com isso, aquele problema de varrer todo o código HTML da página e "(...) *procurar por uma palavra que somente um usuário logado conseguiria ver* (...)" foi resolvida. Como a autenticação é feita por conta do *cookie*, ela será sempre válida independente do usuário estar usando o fórum em português ou inglês.

Segue o código da classe **:)**

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.Cookie;
import java.io.IOException;

public class VBulletinAuth {
    
    // Elementos no HTML
    private final String
    LOGIN_FORM_ID = "navbar_loginform",   // formulário de login
    LOGIN_USER_NAME = "vb_login_username",// input de username
    LOGIN_PASS_NAME = "vb_login_password",// input de senha
    LOGIN_REMEMBER_NAME = "cookieuser";   // checkbox para manter os cookies
    
    
    // Homepage em que exista um formulário de login
    private final String
    HOMEPAGE = "http://www.forum.com.br/forum";
    
    // cookie para verificar se o usuário logou
    private final String
    SESSION_HASH = "bb_sessionhash";
    
    private final WebClient webClient;
    private CookieManager cookies;

    public VBulletinAuth() {
        webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    }
    
    private boolean hasAccount(String user, String pass){
        
        try {
            // Requisição GET para obter a página de login
            HtmlPage homePage = webClient.getPage(HOMEPAGE);
            
            // Procurando pelo formulário de login
            HtmlForm loginForm = null;
            for(HtmlForm form : homePage.getForms())
                if(form.getId().equals(LOGIN_FORM_ID))
                    loginForm = form;
            
            // Obtendo os inputs do formulário  e inserindo os dados de login
            HtmlTextInput usernameInput = loginForm.getInputByName(LOGIN_USER_NAME);
            HtmlPasswordInput passwordInput = loginForm.getInputByName(LOGIN_PASS_NAME);
            HtmlCheckBoxInput rememberMeInput = loginForm.getInputByName(LOGIN_REMEMBER_NAME);
            
            usernameInput.setValueAttribute(user);
            passwordInput.setValueAttribute(pass);
            rememberMeInput.setChecked(true);
            
            // Criando o botão 'fake' de submit e inserindo ele dentro do formulário de login
            HtmlElement fakeSubmitButton = (HtmlElement) homePage.createElement("button");
            fakeSubmitButton.setAttribute("type", "submit");
            loginForm.appendChild(fakeSubmitButton);
            
            // criando uma instância de cookie manager para obter os cookies
            cookies = new CookieManager();
            cookies = webClient.getCookieManager();
            cookies.setCookiesEnabled(true);
            webClient.setCookieManager(cookies);
            
            // Envia o formulário
            fakeSubmitButton.click();
            
            // Verifica se foi criado o cookie de sessao
            for(Cookie cookie : cookies.getCookies())
                if(cookie.getName().equals(SESSION_HASH))
                    return true;

        } catch(IOException | FailingHttpStatusCodeException e){
            // tratamento de exceções
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    // TESTE:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VBulletinAuth auth = new VBulletinAuth();
        
        if(auth.hasAccount("renan", "12345")){
            // é membro do fórum
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A forma "correta" de fazer isso seria utilizar um Web Service que retornasse apenas os dados necessários. Entretanto, em uma breve pesquisa no site e na documentação do VBulletin não encontrei uma só referência só isso. Então resta fazer como já está sendo feito, isto é, através de inspeção do código HTML.

Quanto ao problema da linguagem, é adequado usar um parser como o JSoup ou [Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) para identificar corretamente os elementos da página e então verificar alguma tag HTML que seja comum entre todas as línguas.

Por exemplo, vamos supor que a mensagem de boas vindas seja exibida dentro de uma tag, assim:

```html
<p id="welcome" class="welcome-title">Bem vindo, Usuário</p>
```

Então, ao invés de procurar pelo texto "Bem vindo", talvez seja melhor verificar a tag com a classe `.welcome-title` ou pelo id `welcome`.

Comment: @renan Não existe a possibilidade de você receber uma página antes do servidor processar. Ou está acessando a URL errada, ou faltam informações na requisição, ou é um bug do servidor.